# Elasticsearch:how to choose java client?

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use ELK in my new module.After reading 'get start' doc,I'm trying to write java code to perform index,get,delete operation.
Official doc introduces 'TransportClient'.However,the doc says that 'TransportClient' may be deprecated in further version.It's advised to use 'Java High Level Rest Client'.Furthermore,there is 'Java Low Level Rest Client'.

In conclusion , there are 3 types of clients：

- Java High Level Rest Client
- Java Low Level Rest Client
- TransportClient

By the way,there is another way to use ES API.Use spring boot RestTemplate.I think it's complex because maybe I have to write query json.

I'm so confused that I dont know which one I should use.

My ES version is :5.6.3

Comment: [this article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/the-elasticsearch-java-high-level-rest-client-is-out) should clear things up

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Jest Client](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest) which is simple, basic, and easy to install. I'm using this one, and it works perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your help!However,I choose Java High Level REST Client.Because it's a totally new project.